# What it entails to declare and initialize a pointer in this way: int (*p)[n]

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning about pointers arithmetic and there's an example about processing the columns of a 2D array exploiting pointers, precisely. In order to do that, the code shows a new-to-me declaration of a pointer, here's the snippet:

```c
int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], (*p) [NUM_COLS], i;
...
for (p = &a[0]; p < &a[NUM_ROWS]; p++)
    (*p)[i] = 0;
```

The behavior of this pointer (**(*p) [NUM_COLS]**) is odd to me, since I just learnt that incrementing a pointer acts like incrementing an array subscript allowing you to process the array which is pointed by that pointer. So this is not a regular pointer?

The size (in byte) is the same but what is involved in that declaration given that it represent an entire row while assigned in the *for loop*?

Comment: `(*p)[NUM_COLS]` is a *pointer to array of `int`*. So if you do a `sizeof(*p)` you will get `sizeof(int)*NUM_COLS`. And this is the amount of bytes the pointer will be incremented by if doing pointer addition with `1`.

Comment: [This is what the pointer means](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*p%29%5B8%5D) (I had to substitute `NUM_COLS` for a literal `8`)

Comment: @EugeneSh. actually sizeof(*p) gives 8 byte, like normal pointers

Comment: @dotthor Are you sure? https://ideone.com/4OdaDF . What's your `NUM_COLS`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. you are putting an asterisk before the pointer in the sizeof call, is that right?

Comment: sizeof is not the function and it is not called only evaluated compile time

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/Skg_6cRpS

Comment: Yes. It's the syntax to get the size of the type the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @EugeneSh. True. Eureka! So the pointer is pointing to an array of NUM_COLS size instead of an int. It's stupidly simple but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks to your comments I'm almost getting it, one last question: you say that the amount of space taken by what's pointed by the pointer is the amount incremented by doing pointer addition with 1; it is the same as always happen, even with pointers to int, right?

Comment: If `p` is defined as pointer to type `T`: `T *p;` then `p + 1` will increment `p` by `sizeof(T)` always.

Answer (score 2):

A syntax like

```
 int (*p)[NUM_COLS];
```

essentially defines a pointer `p` which is a pointer to an array of `int`s with `NUM_COLS` element.

So, it can be used as

```
 int arr[NUM_COLS] = {0};
 p = &arr;
```

This has the same properties like all other pointers,

- the type of the pointer is `int (*)[NUM_COLS]`
- the size of the instance pointed to by this pointer is `int [NUM_COLS]`, i.e., size of an `int`, multiplied by the `NUM_COLS`.

Comment: You say "it can be used as" but if i declared a normal pointer like *p, i could've used it to store "&arr", right? So what's really the difference?

Comment: @dotthor No, the types would not match.

Answer (score 0):

As @SouravHhosh wrote it defines the pointer to the array of integers. Any pointer arithmetics is of the multiplication of size of the array.

https://onlinegdb.com/Skg_6cRpS

Answer (score 0):

```
T (*p)[N];
```

declares `p` as a pointer to an N-element array of `T`.  You mainly see them in the following contexts:

- As the result of a higher-dimensioned array expression "decaying" to a pointer expression;
- When allocating memory for a higher-dimensioned array;

As an example of the former, consider the following code:

```
void foo( int (*p)[3] )
{
  // do something with p
}

int main( void )
{
  int arr[2][3];

  foo( arr );
}
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you pass the *expression* `arr` as a parameter to `foo` it is converted from type "2-element array of 3-element array of `int`" (`int [2][3]`) to "pointer to 3-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[3]`).  So the function actually receives a pointer value, not an array.

Because pointer to array syntax is a bit ugly and cumbersome, you can alternately use

```
void foo( int p[][3] ) { ... }
```

for the declaration, but *only* in a function parameter declaration.

As an example of the latter, if you want to dynamically declare a 2D array, you can do this:

```
int (*p)[3] = malloc( 2 * sizeof *p );
```

which allocates space for a 2x3 array of `int` and assigns a pointer to that space to `p`.  The type of the *expression* `p` is "pointer to 3-element array of `int`", so it follows that the type of `*p` is "3-element array of `int`".

Remember that the array subscript operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given a starting address `a`, offset `i` elements (**not bytes**) from that address and dereference the result<sup>1</sup>.  Therefore, it follows that

```
*p == *(p + 0) == p[0]
```

meaning

```
(*p)[i] == (*(p + 0))[i] == (p[0])[i] == p[0][i]
```

So after you've allocated the memory for `p`, you can index into it like any 2D array:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
  for ( size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
    p[i][j] = some_value;
```

General rules:

```
T *a[N];    // a is an N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];  // a is a pointer to an N-element array of T
T *f();     // f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();   // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

Since the subscript `[]` and function call `()` operators have higher precedence than unary `*`, `*a[i]` will be parsed as `*(a[i])` and `*f()` will be parsed as `*(f())`.  If you want to treat `a` as a pointer to an array and `f` as a pointer to a function, you must explicitly group the `*` operator with the identifier using parentheses - `(*a)[i]` and `(*f)()`.

---

1. C was derived from an earlier language called B.  In B, arrays had an explicit pointer to the first element, and that pointer was bound to the array variable.  So, in B, the `*(a + i)` syntax made sense because `a` was always a pointer.  When Ritchie was designing C, he didn't want to keep that explicit pointer in the array, so instead he introduced the rule that array expressions "decay" to pointers except in specific circumstances.